# Prevent a download to saturate all bandwidth on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, tcpip, qos

In Linux, a single download can use all available bandwidth, so that any other connection can't be started. (e.g. if I am downloading updates, I can't surf the web at the same time)

Is there a way to set some kind of fair queueing between different connection, to allow for sharing?

I checked tc with sfq qdisc, but it seems one has to tune it to the current available bandwidth, which could be difficult on xDSL, where maximum downstream bandwidth could not be fully available depending on the provider.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've personally never tried any applications for bandwidth throttling, but if you'd like a good place to see some applications for Linux, check out the "external links" section of the [Bandwidth throttling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_throttling) Wikipedia entry.

Amongst the mentioned solutions, I've heard about [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) and a Squid based implementation (like in the [Bandwidth Limiting HOWTO](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bandwidth-Limiting-HOWTO.html)).

Comment: I tried [wondershaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper), too. The issue with it is that you need to know the total up/down bandwidth beforehand to give it as an input, and that's more annoying when an interface is both on the internet and on a lan, so that you can eventually shape all your LAN related traffic on the same bandwidth of your DSL line.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how it's done, but the rtorrent client (a console bittorrent client) is able to throttle transfers, and therefore does not saturate bandwidth.

Perhaps the source of rtorrent would provide some clues.

Here's a [link](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) to the libtorrent / rtorrent wiki. It has a browse source button